# Exceptions cause crash (Qt SDK 1.2.1 - Qt4.8.1, MinGW, windows)

Tags: windows, qt, mingw, throw

I have an ugly problem and would appreciate any help!! My program crashes on windows any time there an exception is thrown, e.g.:

```
try
{
   throw QString("lala");
}
catch(QString &s)
{
  ...
}
```

I’m using Qt 4.8.1 with MinGW in the QtCreator. I found quite a few discussions and tried

- rebuilding the source code with -exceptions
- adding QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fexceptions

but no change. Windows tells me that the program crashed at the point where I throw the error. Under Linux everything works fine.

Without wanting to discuss the pros and cons of using exceptions at all, I wonder if it’s a problem with Qt or MinGW and what I can do to get rid of the problem.

Comment: I can not reproduce this (Mingw g++ 4.6.2, Qt 4.8.2), see also my [SSCCE](https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/QtException). Can you give some more context? What options are exactly passed to g++?

Comment: What version of MinGW are you using?  Did you build the Qt library, or are you using a pre-built package?

Comment: I'm using Qt with mingw tdm and exceptions work. There was an incompatibility in how exceptions were handled between the pre-compiled version Qt version and the regular mingw. "The MinGW/TDM edition of TDM-GCC offers two different methods of exception handling for your programs: SJLJ (setjmp/longjmp) and DW2 (Dwarf-2)."

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what exactly "crash" means, but if you get a message something like "The application has asked the runtime to exit in an unusual way", that means that your exception got thrown all the way out of the program, without ever being caught by anything.  Since I believe that particular message is produced by the MSVC runtime, the mingw runtime may have a different message with the same meaning, or no message at all.